# XUnit Create Operation Service Mock Failure

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to mock my service's create method like this in the class constructor:

```
serviceMock.Setup(p => p.AddClinic(GetTestClinicModel()))
                .Returns(GetTestClinic());
```

**Mock Model and Mock Entity**

```
private CreateClinicBindingModel GetTestClinicModel()
{
    return new CreateClinicBindingModel()
    {
        Name = "Clinic-3"
    };
}

private Clinic GetTestClinic()
{
    return new Clinic()
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "Clinic-3"
    };
}
```

**Test Method**

```
[Fact]
public void Add_ValidObjectPassed_ReturnsCreatedResponse()
{
    // Act
    var createdResponse = controller.Add(GetTestClinicModel());
    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<CreatedAtActionResult>(createdResponse);
}
```

**Controller Add Method**

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public IActionResult Add(CreateClinicBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    var entity = _service.AddClinic(model);
    return Created(entity);
}
```

So my problem is test getting failure and when I debug `_service.AddClinic()` method it returns null.

The mock service does not return the expected Entity (Clinic).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the setup expects the specific instance created when `GetTestClinicModel()` is invoked.

However that same instance is not used when exercising the test as a totally new instance is created when `GetTestClinicModel()` is invoked again.

Thus the mock will return null since there are separate instances.

Consider changing the setup to use an argument matcher like `It.Is<T>()`

```
serviceMock
    .Setup(_ => _.AddClinic(It.Is<CreateClinicBindingModel>(m => m.Name == "Clinic-3")))
    .Returns(GetTestClinic());
```

The above setup tells the mock to behave as expected when it gets an instance that matches the provided predicate

Comment: Ok it worked. But  actually,  I need more clarification.